# Python: unpacking into array elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

Why does the behavior of unpacking change when I try to make the destination an array element?

```
>>> def foobar(): return (1,2)
>>> a,b = foobar()
>>> (a,b)
 (1, 2)
>>> a = b = [0, 0] # Make a and b lists
>>> a[0], b[0] = foobar()
>>> (a, b)
 ([2, 0], [2, 0])
```

In the first case, I get the behavior I expect. In the second case, both assignments use the last value in the tuple that is returned (i.e. '2'). Why?

Comment: The behaviour of unpacking doesnt change, you are doing a multiple assignment in the 2nd example, not unpacking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `a = b = [0, 0]`, you're making both `a` and `b` point to the *same* list. Because they are mutable, if you change either, you change both. Use this instead:

```
a, b = [0, 0], [0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, Volatility, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`a = b = [0, 0]` # Makes a and b the *same* list

Comment: gnibbler, you beat me too it. :) I just realized my folly and returned to delete the question, and you had already answered. Thank you for the prompt reply.